# Blazor server-side app dies after file download

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server-side app and one of the pages push a file download by using this code:

```
nav.NavigateTo("/download/" + fileName, true);
```

The works well by redirecting the page to the file and pops up the download dialog box. However, after this action, the app dies.

> Error: Circuit has been shut down due to error.

I had to refresh the page to re-establish connection to continue.

Should I have done something differently to allow users download a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For anyone using .NET 5 RC2**

If you are using .NET 5 RC2 or later then this solution will not apply to you and the code shown in the question above should work per [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25646). If you're still having issues it's likely you may be having another problem.

**For anyone using a version prior to .NET 5 RC2**

The thing to keep in mind is that when working with Blazor all communication happens through websockets.  This can present issues when dealing with File downloads as any navigation away from the socket (such as navigating to a static file) will break the connection.

An easy way to handle this would be to use a package like [BlazorDownloadFile](https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorDownloadFile).

In order to use it simply install the nuget with the following command:

```
Install-Package BlazorDownloadFile -Version 2.1.2
```

Next in your ConfigureServices method in your Startup.cs file add the following line:

```
services.AddBlazorDownloadFile();
```

Now you can inject the IBlazorDownloadFileService and use it to download a file.  I've included an example of such usage below where it's just downloading a text file from the same directory as the executing assembly.

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorDownloadFile
@using System.IO
@using System.Reflection
@using System.Threading

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@Message
<br/>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?"/>

<button @onclick="OnClicked">Download File</button>

@code{
    [Inject] IBlazorDownloadFileService BlazorDownloadFileService { get; set; }
    public string Message = String.Empty;
    
    public async Task OnClicked()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "TestDownloadFile.txt");
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        var task = await BlazorDownloadFileService.DownloadFile("testdownload.txt", bytes.ToList(),CancellationToken.None,"application/octet-stream");
        if (task.Succeeded)
        {
            Message = "Successful download!";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = task.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, with this you can easily allow the user to download a file without risking breaking the websocket connection, and you can get feedback on whether there is a problem in order to implement proper error handling.

There are a few notes mentioned in the [Github Project](https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorDownloadFile) that you may need to be mindful of:

> Regarding on some performance test I have done in this library is
> that, base64 string and byte[] performs faster than Stream always.
>
> Since there is not direct conversion between from c# Stream to a
> JavaScript object its a little more expensive this task.
>
> When its base64 this is the most simple data type to transfer and work
> with it.
>
> byte[] gets transformed into base64 string when transfered to
> JavaScript and for some reason it won't work properly when encoding
> cause its base64 representation turns to be something else when going
> after the second partition when gets encoded to base64 string. (If
> anyone knows how to fix or workaround this make a pull request)
>
> Based on the las sentence, a list of bytes gets passed down from c# to
> JavaScript as an array of intergers with the bytes representation on
> JavaScript and this is the reason why I send a IList rather than
> byte[] internally to JavaScript.
>
> The binary representation seems to perform very well since we just
> needed to call Uint8Array and push the binary representation entirely
> into the array to then pass it down to the JavaScript native Blob
> object.

Comment: It is working but only at first time because when I want to download another file nothing happens.

Comment: @sada There are too many variables that could be at play here.  If you have a question based on your project feel free to ask a question on here complete with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The code you show should work -- and has worked for me. The problem appears to be a known (new) issue that is biting many people. You can find more info about the problem here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25646

They say they are working on getting a fix for that out, but there's no ETA at this point. I'm sorry I don't have a decent workaround to share -- I'm still exploring that myself.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25907#issuecomment-705026121 "This issue should be resolved in .NET 5 RC2, which ships on October 13th. If you have the chance, please try that build to resolve your issue. You can also try installing the nightly build of RC2 from https://github.com/dotnet/installer#installers-and-binaries and test that out."